# Yahoo Finance's cryptocurrency volume

Tags: cryptocurrency, yahoo-finance, trading-volume

What is the definition of "volume" in Yahoo Finance's data on [BTC-USD](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD?p=BTC-USD) and [ETH-USD](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ETH-USD?p=ETH-USD)?

Comment: Number of BTC/ETH that have changed hands on the Blockchain. Actual volume may be significantly higher, I believe, as inside-exchange transfers may never make it onto the chain (like when one user on Coinbase sells to another user on Coinbase; Coinbase may just change some balances in their backend instead of actually issuing transactions at times).

Comment: They are not consistent with BTC: blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions and ETH: etherscan.io/chart/tx. They ETH much higher number over BTC.

Comment: Kraken says: "Bitcoin deposits should be credited after 6 network confirmations (normally about 1 hr but can be delayed when Bitcoin network is slow)".(reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/4e64k4/…)

Comment: A bitcoin transaction can contain more than one coin, right? https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000035f4316ea8d597eb311ebc126830e190805ce69332fe09 has a volume of 800, for example.

Comment: @ceejayoz "Number of BTC/ETH that have changed hands on the Blockchain" - how would they know that number? How would you even define that number? Deposits/withdrawals from/to blockchain are not associated to any trades.

Comment: @mastov The blockchain is a giant list of transactions. I've linked to one such transaction. Exchanging to/from fiat wouldn't show up as volume.

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course, but those transactions on the blockchain have *nothing* to do with trading and even less with specific trades between a specific currency pair like BTC/USD. It could be just someone buying a pizza. Or someone cashing out money they put into an exchange. Or someone putting money into an exchange without having traded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing it to [the numbers from coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#markets), which specifies units and breaks down the volume into market places and currency pairs, yields the following results:

- The volume given by Yahoo has to be in USD. If interpreted as BTC, the number would be far too high.
- The volume only includes real BTC/USD trading, *not* BTC/USDT (using [Tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tether_(cryptocurrency)), a pseudo-$ on a blockchain, in order to move classic fiat money easily between exchanges).
- The volume excludes markets that don't charge trading fees, otherwise the volume would be far higher.

Summing up all 24h market volumes of the BTC/USD trading pairs without fees gives a result in $ that is similar in magnitude to the number given by Yahoo as "Volume (24h)". Since the number on Yahoo is slightly lower, I guess that they don't cover smaller exchanges, only the biggest 6 or 7, approximately.

The number "Volume" is the volume traded today (resetting at midnight UTC), the number "Volume (24h)" is the volume traded during the last 24h.